# JMeter - How to batch threads in a thread group

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to batch threads within a thread group? If I set the no. of threads (users) in a thread group to 75, is there way to specify launch 25 threads, wait for completion, launch next 25, wait and launch remaining 25.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

[Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) with `Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by` set to 25

> Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by
>   Number of threads to release at once.

Comment: This will allow me to create the grouping but how to wait for first group to complete before launching the next group.

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 thread groups with 25 threads each.

In the test plan, Check "Run Thread Groups Consecutively". In this way you are sure that next will execute once the first one is completed.